# Kind of ugly- default value for non-existent hash key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

I'm working with an API that returns a hash to represent a product:

```
prod = API.getProduct(id)
prod["name"] => "Widget"
```

The problem arrises because not all products contain identical attribute pages, so I find myself doing a lot of one-off error catching- some products will have a key for `size` or `color`, some won't.

What's the easiest way to get to `prod["non-existent attribute"] => "NA"`?

Comment: Provide the default value to the hash constructor? Add the functionality directly to the hash instance?

Comment: Assuming a normal hash, see [`Hash.new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-c-new)

Comment: @DaveNewton googling those things now... :)

Comment: Thanks.  Didn't know the right language to search for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Dave Newton said, you can add the default value to the hash constructor:

```
hash = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = "NA" }
hash[:anything] == "NA" # => true
```

Or use the `#default` method:

```
hash = Hash.new
hash.default = "NA"
hash[:anything] == "NA" # => true
```

**EDIT** The quick syntax for setting the default value when initializing the hash is:

```
hash = Hash.new("NA")
hash[:anything] == "NA" # => true
```

Comment: I thought you could pass in the default value; has that changed?

Comment: No it hasn't, you're right. I usually use the above syntax mainly just out of habit. I will update my answer to show the quicker syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:  http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-default
You can use `prod.default = "NA"`.